# React Native Animated - Card Won't flip back

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I've been messing around with React Native and I've tried to create a simple card that flips around on press (back and forth):

I had it working as a class component but now I've tried to refactor to a functional component and its only flipping one way but not back on second press.

Can someone advise me what I've missed? :/

I tried using useState and useEffect for the value and animated value etc, but no dice...

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Text } from 'react-native';
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';

const App = () => {

        let animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
        let value = 0;

        animatedValue.addListener(({ value }) => {
            this.value = value;
        })

        let frontInterpolate = animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 180],
            outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
        })
        let backInterpolate = animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 180],
            outputRange: ['180deg', '360deg']
        })
        let frontOpacity = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [89, 90],
        outputRange: [1, 0]
        });

        let backOpacity = animatedValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [89, 90],
        outputRange: [0, 1]
        });

        let elevationFront = animatedValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 25],
          outputRange: [10, 0]
          })

        let elevationBack = animatedValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [155, 180],
          outputRange: [0, 10]
          })

        const flipCard = () => {
          if (value >= 90) {
            Animated.spring(animatedValue,{
              toValue: 0,
              friction: 8,
              tension: 10
            }).start();
          } else {
            Animated.spring(animatedValue,{
              toValue: 180,
              friction: 8,
              tension: 10
            }).start();
          }
        }


        const frontAnimatedStyle = {
        transform: [{ rotateY: frontInterpolate}]
        }
        const backAnimatedStyle = {
        transform: [{ rotateY: backInterpolate }]
        }


    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => flipCard()} >
          <View>
                <Animated.View style={[frontAnimatedStyle, styles.paperFront,{elevation: elevationFront}, {opacity: frontOpacity}]}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 20,paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, color: 'black',lineHeight: 20}}>
                    Title Front {value} - <Text style={{fontSize: 8}}>KPI</Text>
                  </Text>
                    <View style={{position: "absolute", paddingTop: 3, right: 8}}>
                      <TabBarIcon style={{color: "black"}} name={"md-more"} />
                    </View>
                </Animated.View>

                <Animated.View style={[backAnimatedStyle, styles.paperBack, {elevation: elevationBack}, {opacity: backOpacity}]}>
                  <Text>Back title {value}</Text>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    paperFront : {
      marginHorizontal: 15,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      minHeight: 200,
      borderRadius: 5,
      marginBottom: 15,

    },
    paperBack : {
      top: -215,
      marginHorizontal: 15,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      minHeight: 200,
      borderRadius: 5,
      marginBottom: 15,
    }
});

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to  call your "value" not "this.value", but since you already got "value" parameter I suggest you change the variable name:

```
 let val = 0;

 animatedValue.addListener(({ value}) => {
    val = value;
  });
```

P.S: don't forget to change your calls to "value" variable into "val"

Comment: I have the same problem bro, I can't understand what does addListener do in this animation? and why do you set if >=90

Comment: Hi is it possible to auto flip the card back after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

fix it

```
          if (this.value >= 90) {
```

[in expo](https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/animated)

Comment: hi, i tried following your code but for some reason the cards are not getting flipped at the same position